# The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

**"babel-eslint": "9.0.0"**

*Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-eslint was detected higher up in the tree:*

Comment: Hi, have you tried the steps suggested in the error message?

Comment: yeah but i get the same shit error

Comment: Same here, problems with `webpack` and `babel-eslint`, trying downgrading `react-scripts` from 2.1.2 to 2.1.1 didn't work, there is a issue open on GitHub here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14518

Comment: Hey @Chawki_726  , try using `npm ls babel-eslint`and check what package is downgrading or upgrading `bable-eslint`. I have the same issue but with `webpack` and `react-recaptcha-v3` package has introduced the issue for me.

Comment: i solve the issue by deleting the global babel-eslint

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM start returns error, "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528222/npm-start-returns-error-there-might-be-a-problem-with-the-project-dependency-t)

Answer (score 38):

create `.env` file in your project file and add the following statement

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

Save the file

Remove node_modules, yarn.lock, package.lock

Then reinstall node_modules with

```
npm install
```

This should work

Comment: may I know the behind the scenes

Comment: While this does work, it is not necessarily the right solution, it only ignores the issue causing the warning. It clearly states, "That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues." This can happen due to a number of reasons, multiple CRA's with different versions within a monorepo are trying to be installed at the root level, or a conflict with globally installed node_modules if installed in an unintended directory.

Comment: @zilj do you have a better solution? This problem stems directly from an incompatibility of the eslint used by create-react-app and the newer versions of eslint. Unless facebook addresses the problem and solves it the right way, I think this solution is the best we have.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem and do all the suggested steps but the problem still, so, my error is that i have a reactApp inside other Javascript App i had this structure.

```
--MyProjects
----NodeJsApp
----node_modules of NodeJsApp
----package.json of NodeJsApp
----ReactApp
------node_modules of ReactApp
------package.json of ReactApp
```

The problem solved to me deleting my ReactApp node_modules directory, then i do a reestructure of my directories because i have a disaster.

```
--MyProjects
----NewDirectory (inside all about NodeJsApp)
------node_modules of NodeJsApp
------package.json of NodeJsApp
----ReactApp
------package.json of ReactApp
```

After that i do :

```
npm install
```

and then `npm start`  and my problem has fixed, i think that the problem is that the parent directory cant have a javascript /nodeJs/ project or something that have node_modules .

Comment: This is the real answer to this issue. I was having a node_modules folder otside my reactApp directory also which was creating the issue. Thanks man

Comment: But why npm takes deps from parents node_modules, if it firstly must takes local node_modules in current directory?

Comment: Thank you for being you:)  I too had node_modules, as well as package-lock.json and yarn.lock in my parent projects directory. I deleted them, as well as the ones in my local project folder, then reinstalled in the project. Fixed! That had been an issue for a long time. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Part of the output you provided says:

> Check if C:\Users\chawki\node_modules\babel-eslint is outside your project directory. For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

Browse to `C:\Users\chawki\node_modules\` and delete the `babel-eslint` folder, or simply delete `C:\Users\chawki\node_modules`.

Comment: This solved my problem because I accidentally yarn install on the parent folders. This would be a noob mistake. The entire `node_modules` folder is essentially a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Here What i did...

1. `C:\user\[yourUserName]\node_modules\babel-eslint` and delete the file
2. `C:\user\[yourUserName]\node_modules\eslint` and delete the file

Answer (score 5):

I just deleted the `node_modules` folder (for me it was `C:\user\[yourUserName]\node_modules\`) and re-installed it.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to create .env file there is another alternative you can pass the `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` directly in the script.
For Example

```
   "start": "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true react-scripts start",
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete your `eslint` and `babel-eslint` file from your node modules on your computer e.g. `-C:\Users\vishnu\node_modules` `-delete eslint` and `babel-eslint` file.

In your project:

```
yarn remove eslint
yarn add --dev eslint@6.1.0
```

```
yarn remove babel-eslint
yarn add --dev babel-eslint@10.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

in package.json

```
resolutions:{
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0"
}
```

if you reinstall your all dependencies, you will be forcing "babel-eslint" to be version "9.0.0". if you start your app, you will have no issue.

Comment: Well that didn't work at all `if you reinstall your all dependencies, you will be forcing "babel-eslint" to be version "9.0.0". if you start your app, you will have no issue.` this didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I installed webpack as a global package... after i deleted webpact and run npm install, the problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a global webpack package or somewhere higher up the directory structure.
In my case, I had it globally installed. Deleting and then running npm install and then npm start worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm ls babel-eslint` and see which dependencies are using it or installing another version. Try updating those libraries.

It worked for me.