# 'yarn start' throws babel-eslint error MacOS, how do I fix this error?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, yarnpkg

I am trying to create a React.js App however once created and I try to run using 'yarn start' in the terminal I get this:

```
yarn run v1.12.3
$ react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-eslint": "10.0.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/olliesaunderson/node_modules/babel-eslint (version: 9.0.0) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /Users/olliesaunderson/node_modules/babel-eslint is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-eslint in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have tried following the steps suggested however none of this seems to works. I have also tried `yarn add --exact react-scripts@3.0.1` and `yarn cache clean`

Comment: try running ```yarn``` in your project.

Comment: @JuniusL. I already tried that thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @dmitri7 do I add this under dependencies?

Comment: Actually this is not a good idea. Better to remove node_modules, package-lock.json and reinstall from scratch. Problem is that you have babel-eslint of older version in your node_modules (said so in error description). Personally, I would remove babel-eslint from node_modules and run npm install. This should fix the dependency.

Comment: @dmitri7 I deleted the node_modules folder and yarn.lock, then ran 'yarn install' followed by 'yarn start'... same error still

Comment: @OllieTrute check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000294/the-react-scripts-package-provided-by-create-react-app-requires-a-dependency

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

So as the error shows, there is an existing folder of 'babel-eslint' somewhere higher up in my dependency tree. All I had to do was search in finder for that folder and then delete it, once done you can just 'yarn install' again and 'yarn start' then it should work :)

I have no idea where this other 'babel-eslint' folder came from btw...